# How do I fill a column with one value in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column with consecutive digits in a Pandas DataFrame.

```
A
1
2
3
4
```

I would like to change all those values to a simple string, say "foo", resulting in

```
A
foo
foo
foo
foo
```

Answer (score 150, accepted):

Just select the column and assign like normal:

```
In [194]:
df['A'] = 'foo'
df

Out[194]:
     A
0  foo
1  foo
2  foo
3  foo
```

Assigning a scalar value will set all the rows to the same scalar value

Comment: To me it only fills the first item... I have to do a fillna(method='ffill') to make it work... that is strange

Comment: This also returns "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame."

Comment: @FedericoGentile I was having the same issue, until I realised I was assigning a series with a single element. Once I accessed the element with `foo[0]` It worked as above.

Comment: This gives `ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index`

Answer (score 22):

The good answer above throws a warning. You can also do:

```
df.insert(0, 'A', 'foo')
```

where 0 is the index where the new column will be inserted.

Answer (score 8):

You can also exploit the power of the `.loc` property by addressing all the rows using `:` as the argument. Say that your DataFrame is called `df`:

```py
df.loc[:]['A'] = 'foo'
```

Resulting in

```py
     A
0  foo
1  foo
2  foo
3  foo
```

Comment: This gives me "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame."

Comment: Do you expect this to be more efficient on large datasets?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the method [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html#pandas.DataFrame.assign):

```
df = df.assign(A='foo')
```

Comment: Thanks - also note to save time of others, it is written A in this case and not 'A'.

Comment: This was the only way that worked to eliminate the "setting on copy" warning. `loc` and `copy()` wouldn't work since I have a complex situation where I am looping over a dictionary of dataframes, within a loop over a master dataframe with metadata, and augmenting those dataframes with that metadata. Thanks.

Comment: @Rafs Thank you for upvote. Warnings are not errors, and it's not always possible to avoid them in Pandas.

Answer (score 4):

For this to work without receiving the slice error/warning, you can do this:

```
df.loc[:]['A'] = 'foo'
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also try `pd.Series.replace`:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].replace(df['A'], 'foo')
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     A
0  foo
1  foo
2  foo
3  foo
```