# adding a new column to pandas data frame and fill it with 2 values till the end of the column

Tags: python, r, pandas

I want to achieve this simple R code in pandas with simple syntax

here R code

```css
> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
> mtcars$year <- c(1973, 1974)
> head(mtcars)
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb year
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4 1973
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4 1974
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1 1973
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1 1974
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 1973
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 1974
```

as you can see column year has been added to the data frame and filled with two repetitive values  till the column ends

How can I achieve this in pandas with simple code

please note that I don't want to use for loop in the solution as it will take so much time if I'm working with big data set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When adding a column to a Pandas DF, you must supply an object whose length matches the number of rows in the DF (unless every value is the same, in which case a [scalar value can be assigned to the column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811971/how-do-i-fill-a-column-with-one-value-in-pandas/34811984)). To do this, you could use a generator expression that repeats the elements of a list longer than the length of the DF, then slice it to the correct length:

```
mtcars['year'] = ([1973, 1974] * (len(mtcars) // 2 + 1))[:len(mtcars)]
```

Thanks to [MaxU](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5741205) for inspiration with this solution.

For the case where the DF has an **even number of rows** you could simply repeat the elements of a list to the length of the DF:

```
mtcars['year'] = [1973, 1974] * (len(mtcars) // 2)
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: you can still use your solution for DFs with any number of rows if you slightly modify it: `([1973, 1974] * (len(mtcars) // 2 + 1))[:len(mtcars)]`

Comment: Really nice! I will add this to the answer

Comment: that's a great  tweak @MaxU

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy tile (much faster than the list generation technique):

```
import numpy as np

years = (1973, 1974)
mtcars['year'] = np.tile(years, int(len(mtcars) / len(years)) + 1)[:len(mtcars)]
```

Numpy tile with a 1 million row dataframe:

```
mtcars = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1000000))

years = (1973, 1974)
mtcars['year'] = np.tile(years, int(len(mtcars) / len(years)) + 1)[:len(mtcars)]

CPU times: user 0 ns, sys: 4 ms, total: 4 ms
Wall time: 3.81 ms
```

List generation with a 1 million row dataframe:

```
mtcars['year'] = ([1973, 1974] * (len(mtcars) // 2 + 1))[:len(mtcars)]

CPU times: user 140 ms, sys: 0 ns, total: 140 ms
Wall time: 136 ms
```

Answer (score 0):

I propose this:

```
def new_vect(vect, n_row):
    l_vect = len(vect)
    l_new_vect = n_row / l_vect + 1
    new_vect = vect * l_new_vect
    return new_vect[:n_row]

mtcars['year'] = new_vect([1973,1974],mtcars.shape[0])
```

it's maybe a bit complex, but it will work also for even number of row