# Pandas - fill specific number of rows in a column with one value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a DataFrame column of 40 rows that is filled entirely with `0`'s, except for three lines which have numbers on them. And one column that only has one valuable number on it.

```
new_column new_column2  
0                                                          0              0  
1                                                          0              0  
2                                                          0              0  
3                                                          0              0  
4                                                          0              0  
5                                                          0              0  
6                                                          0              0  
7                                                          0              0  
8                                                          0              0  
9                                                          0              0  
10                                                       NaN     $21,151.67  
11                                                         0              0  
12                                                         0              0  
13                                                         0              0  
14                                                         0              0  
15                                                         0              0  
16                                                         0              0  
17                                                         0              0  
18                                                         0              0  
19                                                         0              0  
20                                                         0              0  
21                                                         0              0  
22                                                         0              0  
23                                                         0              0  
24                                                         0              0  
25                                                $58,500.00           None  
26                                                         0              0  
27                                                         0              0  
28                                                         0              0  
29                                                         0              0  
30                                                         0              0  
31                                                         0              0  
32                                                         0              0  
33                                                         0              0  
34                                                         0              0  
35                                                         0              0  
36                                                         0              0  
37                                                         0              0  
38                                                         0              0  
39                                                         0              0  
40                                                $57,750.00           None
```

Is it possible to take those numbers of value and fill the column with them, until they hit another occurrence of a valuable number anyway?

So `$21,151.67` would fill in all the rows from line 1 to line 10.

`$50,500.00` would fill in all the rows from lines 11-25.

And `$57,750.00` would fill in the rows from 25-40.

I know that I could do a simple command such as the one listed here ([How do I fill a column with one value in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811971/how-do-i-fill-a-column-with-one-value-in-pandas/34811984)) to fill up the column, but these numbers will change on each file that I run my code on so it needs to be powerful enough to arbitrarily take whatever numbers appear and align them in the correct rows.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Wat about Nan values? Do you need to replace them also?

Comment: @SayPy NaNs aren't my biggest concern. Just aligning those price values to their correct rows is

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace `0`'s and None with actual missing values, then forward-fill missing values along rows:

```
df[(df == '0') | (df == 'None')] = None
df = df.fillna(method = 'ffill', axis=1)
```

now `df['new_column2']` contains the values you want to back-fill with. So, simply use the `backfill` method of `fillna()` to fill the gaps.

```
df['new_column2'] = df['new_column2'].fillna(method = 'backfill')
df['new_column'] = df['new_column2']
```

gives:

```
    new_column new_column2
0   $21,151.67  $21,151.67
1   $21,151.67  $21,151.67
2   $21,151.67  $21,151.67
3   $21,151.67  $21,151.67
4   $21,151.67  $21,151.67
5   $21,151.67  $21,151.67
6   $21,151.67  $21,151.67
7   $21,151.67  $21,151.67 
8   $21,151.67  $21,151.67
9   $21,151.67  $21,151.67
10  $21,151.67  $21,151.67
11  $58,500.00  $58,500.00
12  $58,500.00  $58,500.00
       ...          ...
```

Comment: Hmm. Your end printout looks like it's perfect. But adding your code I received `TypeError: Could not compare ['0'] with block values` pointing towards the line `fish_frame[(fish_frame == '0') | (fish_frame == 'None')] = None`

Comment: OK. I think it's because the strings in your dataframe contain whitespaces. Probably they are something like  `.....0`, whereas I have assumed that they are `0`. Try to run  `df = df.applymap(str.strip)` to strip the whitespaces before replacing missing values

Comment: It came back with the error `TypeError: ("descriptor 'strip' requires a 'str' object but received a 'float'", 'occurred at index 1')`. So that means these `0`s are integers and they need to be strings in order for this code to work? Is that easily fixed?

Comment: Please check the datatype of the columns with `df.dtypes`. Again, I have assumed that your columns were strings, not floats. If your columns are floats, then you need to remove the quotes from around `0`s and `None` like this `fish_frame[(fish_frame == 0) | (fish_frame == None)] = None`.

Comment: `df.dtypes` reveals that all the columns are `objects` except for one column which is `int64`

Comment: Ok. This means that likely your columns are mixed datatypes. Please check if this works `fish_frame[(fish_frame == 0)] = None` (with no quotes around `0`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149010/discussion-between-vincep-and-theprowler).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.iloc` method and slice the index ranges as you'd like - refer to my code snippet below.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0, 40), columns=['new_column', 'new_column2'],
                  dtype='float')

df.iloc[0:10] = 21156.67
df.iloc[10:25] = 50500.00
df.iloc[25:40] = 57750.00
```

Hopefully this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Ohhh does that just slice out all the valid numbers from those columns?

Comment: Because if that's the case that is pretty powerful and smart. No matter what other junk those new columns are filled with, that could extract the important information, am I understanding that right?

Comment: It didn't end up working though. It just printed columns of `NaN`s

Comment: @theprowler You must have done something wrong then, I ran this at work on a Windows machine, and just now at home - both times worked perfectly.

Comment: Are those last three lines supposed to be added or are those the printout? Because if I have to manually type what numbers are in the original dataframe it won't work because I have to run this code on hundreds of files.

Comment: @theprowler the values added to the last line are simply for example's sake, as you said those were the values you wanted in those ranges. What you should take away here is the ability of using `.iloc` to slice indice ranges, and assign values to them. It is up to you on how to implement `.iloc`. Additionally, from your second comment, you are understanding that correctly, you can extract information or insert the information using `.iloc`, and pandas documentation might be helpful as well - http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/

Comment: Ohh so `.iloc` is literally just a method to index. I see. That's useful but it's not exactly what I need here. I need to take a value that's already in the dataframe and apply it to the entire column it's already in, up until it hits another value.

Comment: I believe @VinceP 's answer is exactly what you're looking for then.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) function gives you an option to back or forward fill to the next/last valid observation.
For your case you would need to replace the None and NaN with a valid value and then replace 0 with an invalid one (meaning np.nan). Then you can use fillna with backward fill.

```
df[['foo', 'bar']].fillna('anker', inplace=True)
df[['foo', 'bar']].replace({0:np.nan})
df[['foo', 'bar']].fillna(methode='bfill')
```

The remaining anker values can then be replaced with whatever value you care.

Hope that helps.