# Loop which every iteration will replace one column from a dataframe with zeros

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I want to perform Sensitivity Analysis for classification models in Python.

So I want to check how lack of every column will affect the metrics.
I prepared function which returns metrics from original test set.

```
def score_metrics(model, 
                  X_test,
                  y_test):

y_pred = model.predict(X_test) #predicted values from oryginal dataset

cm_orig = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

tp = cm_orig[1, 1]
fp = cm_orig[0, 1]
fn = cm_orig[1, 0]
tn = cm_orig[0, 0]

score_orig_precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred)
score_orig_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
score_orig_recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred)
score_orig_specificity = tn/(tn+fp)
score_orig_F1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred)

results = {'Feature': 'orginal',
           'Precision': score_orig_precision,
           'Accuracy': score_orig_accuracy,
           'Recall': score_orig_recall,
           'Specificity': score_orig_specificity,
           'F1 score': score_orig_F1}

return results
```

I want perform the same but for X_test which with every iteration will have one column values replaced with 0.

For example if this would be X_test:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
    5   7   11  12  6
   11   32  11  13  6
```

I would like to check those metrics for:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
    0   7  11  12   6
    0  32  11  13   6

    A   B   C   D   E
    5   0  11  12   6
   11   0  11  13   6

    A   B   C   D   E
    5   7   0   12  6
   11   32  0   13  6
```

and so on.
And my question is to edit above code (or suggest something else) which help me to achieve it.
Later I would like to have this outcome in Pandas DataFrame but it's enough to show me up to dictionary state.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I fill a column with one value in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34811971/how-do-i-fill-a-column-with-one-value-in-pandas)

Comment: Thank you, yes I need this but main issue is to create temporal data frames operate on them and saving results in several iterations :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from your example, you actually dont want to drop the column, just give 0 value during the iteration. Then you can use:

```
for c in df.columns:
    newDF = df.copy(deep=True)
    newDF[c] = 0
    # Here you opperate with the new DF in this instance
```

One option to integer this in your existing code:

```
def getting_results(y_pred, y_test):
    cm_orig = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

    tp = cm_orig[1, 1]
    fp = cm_orig[0, 1]
    fn = cm_orig[1, 0]
    tn = cm_orig[0, 0]

    score_orig_precision = precision_score(y_test, y_pred)
    score_orig_accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
    score_orig_recall = recall_score(y_test, y_pred)
    score_orig_specificity = tn/(tn+fp)
    score_orig_F1 = f1_score(y_test, y_pred)

    results = {'Feature': 'orginal',
               'Precision': score_orig_precision,
               'Accuracy': score_orig_accuracy,
               'Recall': score_orig_recall,
               'Specificity': score_orig_specificity,
               'F1 score': score_orig_F1}

    return results


def score_metrics(model, X_test, y_test):

    for c in X_test.columns:
        newX_test = X_test.copy(deep=True)
        newX_test[c] = 0
        
        y_pred = model.predict(newX_test) #predicted values from oryginal dataset
        getting_results(y_pred, y_test)
```

Comment: @Aly This solution is already using dataframe. Is it what you need?

Comment: Yes thank you. Very helpful. I have now issue how I can append this solution? In my function I'm returning back metrics as dictionary. What I should add before/after this loop to get metrics for all columns? I add ```results = {'Feature': column``` in dict and it is fine but it is showing only last outcome

Comment: ```full_output = []
for c in modeling_columns:
    output = score_sensitivity_without(model = acrylamide_model, column = c, X_test = X_test, y_test = y_test)
    full_output.append(output)``` I solved it, thank you very much :)

Comment: @Aly how to integer it, is up to you, however I gave you a possible approach